# Responsive hero image with button + boxed text problems

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I am trying to make a full width hero image with an h1 header, boxed text with 2 sizes of text inside plus a button. I have been wrestling with this all day and it just doesnt seem to work the way i'd like it to. Any help would be really appreciated.

thanks

Images:
[How it looks at the moment with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hujdf.png)

If you notice it is not going full width (gap on the left).

[This is how i would like it to look or close enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3cuj.png)

```
 //css//    

.hero-image {
background-image: url("image.jpg");
background-position: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
padding: 50px;
}

.hero-text {
position: relative;
color: #154774;
}

.hero-text button {
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px 20px;
color: white;
background-color: #00adee;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
bottom: 50px;  
}

.hero-text button:hover {
background-color: #0597c4;
color: white;
}
.herotext2 {
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 color: white;
 background-color: red;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 200px; 
 line-height: 1.4;
 }
 </style>


 //html//

<div class="hero-image">
<div class="hero-text">
<h1 style="font-size:40px">IT support for<br>your business<br>as easy as<br>child’s play</h1>
<p class="herotext2">All inclusive IT GDPR service packages from £33 p/m</p>
<button>Try it for free today</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Updated image:
[Updated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN93k.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.hero-image {
     background-image: url("https://beerdeluxe.com.au/hawthorn/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2017/05/hero-placeholder.png");
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     padding: 50px;
}
 .hero-text {
     position: relative;
     color: #154774;
     text-align:right;
}
 .hero-text h1 {
     font-size:40px;
     margin-right:15%;
}
 .hero-text h1 .italic {
     font-style: italic;
}
 .hero-text button {
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     color: white;
     background-color: #00adee;
     text-align: center;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: bold;
     bottom: 50px;
     max-width: 150px;
     margin-top: 25px;
}
 .hero-text button:hover {
     background-color: #0597c4;
     color: white;
}
 .herotext2 {
     position:relative;
     border-radius: 5px;
     padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
     color: white;
     background-color: red;
     font-size: 20px;
     width: 200px;
     line-height: 1.4;
     margin: 0 0 0 auto;
     text-align:left;
}
 .herotext2 .no {
     font-size: 135px;
     line-height: 130px;
     font-weight: 600;
}
 .herotext2 .tag {
    position: absolute;
     bottom: 26px;
     right: 30px;
     font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image">
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>IT support for your<br> business - <span class="italic">as easy as<br>child’s play</span></h1>
<p class="herotext2">All inclusive IT GDPR service packages from <span class="no">£33</span><span class="tag">p/m</span></p>
<button>Try it for free today</button>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/pwxf73z8/16/

I have updated your html format and added new styles..Now it appears as your design but you need to apply relevant font family.

It works nice. Let me know if there is any issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I think i am pretty close now, just seems to be an issue with the image extending the full width and the text staying within the boundaries of the box and button. Ive added a photo in the original question to show the issue. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN93k.png

Comment: @j4mes83, I saw issues raised, but couldn't solve them without seeing code.send me a jsfiddle or snippet link.Then I can help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply, sorry i am not much of a coder so not sure what you'd like me to send, i am using wordpress. I can link to you to the dev page? Otherwise i can try and find what you need with a bit more info, thanks again

Comment: @j4mes83, yes, link me to your dev page. send me the url please.

Comment: @j4mes83, I couldn't find your banner area. Where have you placed them?

Comment: It seems to be in section class = content wide and then in a div class=hero-image. Sorry if that's not what you mean but as i said this is all a bit new to me.

Comment: @j4mes83 update your styles as per below jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/pwxf73z8/29/

Comment: Great! Can't thank you enough. Thanks so much, you've been a lifesaver.

Comment: Just one thing, it still does not go full width, is that potentially because of the image itself? Thanks

Comment: @j4mes83, According to my memory about your coding, you need to place banner div tag, outside the wrapper area...

Comment: Sorry how would i do that? <div class="hero-image">
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>IT support for your<br> business - <span class="italic">as easy as<br>child’s play</span></h1>
<p class="herotext2">All inclusive IT GDPR service packages from <span class="no">£33</span><span class="tag">p/m</span></p>
<button>Try it for free today</button>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @j4mes83, Send me your website and pw again. I'll tell exactly what you want to do.Thanks.

Comment: thanks again for taking the time out for this :) http://jms-securedata.co.uk/home-page-new/ pw=jms1

Comment: @j4mes83, Check this screenshot and place divs correctly. https://imgur.com/RYdCFyh
You need to place .hero-image div with it's content outside the content section..Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: thanks for the help, i think i will only be able to do that if i modify the default php wordpress template which was previously made by someone else. It's fine though, now i know, i can potentially make a work around, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `absolute` positioning the elements inside the hero image. This way, you can *force* them to stay at certain point inside it, by setting top, right, bottom and left of each one.
Don't forget to set parent hero div to `position: relative`.